Vmware workstation pro 17.0.2 - hard disk advanced setting -grayed
I am trying to change second hard disk to be independent in VM like in section 10 in the link,
but mode "independent" is grayed,
How can I fix it?
 here is a picture

Please list all of the steps and methods you have tried so far. Add this information to the question using the EDIT button.

Ok, I solved that problem.
I had to delete snapshot

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
